# How to add SSAS excel report on SharePoint page?

Tags: 2013, excel, ssas

We have a Excel Sheet which has got a Chart that is generated from an Analysis DB (Excel connects to Analysis DB with a particular credential which is setup when connecting to Analysis DB via Excel).

We need to show this on a SharePoint page. Please advice on step by step best practice.

Here is what I do:

1. Configure excel service application -> Trusted file location
2. Configure secure store application (this is needed to enable data refresh via excel web access webpart)
3. Add excel document to a doc library
4. Add excel web access webpart to sharepoint page and specify the path to this doc.
5. Done!

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup Secure Store - This is require to store the Credentials for connecting to External Source
2. Set up a Data Connection Library
3. Set up a Library to house the Excel Reports
4. Create And Store The Connection File
5. Upload and publish Excel File
6. Edit Page and Add Excel Web Access web part

Detailed steps can be found here http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/12/connecting-to-cubes-and-external-data-with-excel-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Hi Amal. I have already setup the credentials in the dialog box in excel to connect to analysis db. Do I still need to use secure store?

Comment: Why do I need to configure both Secure store and DCL?